# Connecting to powershell over ssl from linux using python & pywinrm

Tags: python, linux, powershell, ssl

I'm trying to get python remote powershell working using pywinrm from a docker container but hitting a wall connecting to the remote host i cant find a working example anywhere with ssl working (and not going to use it without) but below is what i've pieced together from the docs and my basic understanding of python, hopefully someone can see where i'm going wrong

## Things i've checked

- i checked that i can connect via another windows machine using `Enter-PSSession -ComputerName x.x.x.x -UseSSL -Credential $creds;`
- i've tried using both python3 & python2 and get the same error in both
- i've tried the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35217606/connecting-using-pywinrm-with-ssl) which gets me the same error in the post even if i install my self signed cert from the windows machine (used the accepted answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/645818/how-to-install-certificates-for-command-line) to add the cert) which isn't suprising without it as there is no server_cert_validation='ignore' parameter but kind of odd with it
- i've tried base64 encoding the password as the docs mention it needs it but never use it in any examples
- i've tried adding the realm/machine name to the username (not on a domain btw)

Here are the details from the python3 attempt.

## Versions

```
python3 --version
Python 3.4.2

pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages (python 3.4)

pip show pywinrm 
Name: pywinrm
Version: 0.2.2
Summary: Python library for Windows Remote Management
Home-page: http://github.com/diyan/pywinrm/
Author: Alexey Diyan
Author-email: alexey.diyan@gmail.com
License: MIT license
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages
Requires: six, xmltodict, requests, requests-ntlm
```

## Python Code (open_winrm.py)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import winrm
import base64

p = winrm.protocol.Protocol(
        endpoint='https://<some_ip_here>:5986/wsman',
        transport='ssl',
        username='<some_username_here>',
        password='<some_password_here>',
        server_cert_validation='ignore')

shell_id = p.open_shell()
command_id = p.run_command(shell_id, 'ipconfig', ['/all'])
std_out, std_err, status_code = p.get_command_output(shell_id, command_id)
p.cleanup_command(shell_id, command_id)
p.close_shell(shell_id)
```

## Result

```
File "./open_winrm.py", line 13, in <module>
    shell_id = p.open_shell()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/winrm/protocol.py", line 132, in open_shell
    res = self.send_message(xmltodict.unparse(req))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/winrm/protocol.py", line 207, in send_message
    return self.transport.send_message(message)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/winrm/transport.py", line 190, in send_message
    raise InvalidCredentialsError("the specified credentials were rejected by the server")
winrm.exceptions.InvalidCredentialsError: the specified credentials were rejected by the server
```

## Dockerfile

```
FROM node:7.7.3

ENV DEBCONF_NONINTERACTIVE_SEEN="true" \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive"

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y upgrade && \
    apt-get -y autoremove && \
    apt-get clean

RUN apt-get install -y etherwake locales locales-all python3 && \
    curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3 && \
    python3 -m pip install pywinrm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end i gave up with pywinrm as i could never get it to connect and used ruby with the [winrm gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/winrm/versions/1.8.1) which worked on the first attempt